# sorting a list containing dates as a substring

Tags: python

I have a list of strings something like this
   As you can make out there is a date embedded at the start of the string and also 
   at the end of the string.

```
 a = ["08/19/2014100%ABC10/02/2014F","02/12/2012100%ABC10/02/2014F",
      "08/29/2014100%ABC10/02/2012F"]
```

I wanted to sort this list based on the date substring.

The way I wanted to implement is by extract the date, sort the date and join the date with the substring, but it's becoming too complicated.

Comment: Can you show us some code from what you've tried?

Comment: by which date do you want to sort then? see `datetime.strptime` to extract date from strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `sorted()` with the `key` argument set to a function that extracts and converts the date from the string into a `datetime.datetime` object.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = ["08/19/2014100%ABC10/02/2014F","02/12/2012100%ABC10/02/2014F", "08/29/2014100%ABC10/02/2012F"]
>>> sorted_a = sorted(a, key=lambda s: datetime.strptime(s[:10], '%m/%d/%Y'))
>>> sorted_a
['02/12/2012100%ABC10/02/2014F', '08/19/2014100%ABC10/02/2014F', '08/29/2014100%ABC10/02/2012F']
```

Or, if you want to sort in place:

```
>>> a.sort(key=lambda s: datetime.strptime(s[:10], '%m/%d/%Y'))
>>> a
['02/12/2012100%ABC10/02/2014F', '08/19/2014100%ABC10/02/2014F', '08/29/2014100%ABC10/02/2012F']
```

If you actually mean to sort on the last date in the string just change the key function to:

```
lambda s: datetime.strptime(s[-11:-1], '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks mate . It was of great help.

Comment: @AndroidBeginner:   np :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code defines a custom sorting function `compare` which takes two elements from your list, and sorts them based on the date which appears at the start of each string.  If you wanted to use the dates embedded at the end of the strings, you can modify the code accordingly.

```
def compare(item1, item2):
    format = '%m/%d/%Y' #changed the date format
    # convert string dates to Date type
    date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(item1[:10], format).date() #removed comma from item1[:,10]
    date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(item2[:10], format).date() #same as above

    if date1 < date2:
        return -1
    elif date1 > date2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

a = ["08/19/2014100%ABC10/02/2014F","02/12/2012100%ABC10/02/2014F",
  "08/29/2014100%ABC10/02/2012F"]

a.sort(compare)
```